# Slow performance with cumulative count in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have some performance issues in a chartcontroller. I have two arrays: one array with dates and one array with entities which contain also a date. I want to cumulative count the date values of the entities.

I do have a bit of code but it's slow (I have to wait 3 - 4 seconds for 68k rows in the data array).

My code:

```
// Loop through the SQL results and count on date
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        foreach ($dates as $date => $value) {
            // $row['appointmentDate'] is a DateTime object
            if ($date >= $row['appointmentDate']->format('Ymd')) {
                $dates[$date]++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a smarter / better / faster way to achieve this?

**// Edit**

Jack gived me the push I needed and I solved my performance issue.

The code above took 38000 ms to complete, the code beneath 5700ms.

```
    usort($result, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['appointmentDate'] > $b['appointmentDate'];
    });

    // Loop through the SQL results and count on date
    for ($i = 0; $i++; $i <= count($result)) {
        $i++;
        $dates[$result[$i]['appointmentDate']->format('Ymd')] = $i;
    }
```

Thanks for your help Jack!

Comment: Count your dates in DBMS through `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: That could be a solution. I will look in to it

Comment: can't you query highest date from your Database? Like with MySQL Max? Most DBAL/ORM Systems allow that as well

Comment: I'm using Doctrine2 as ORM but I can't find a way to do a cumulative count with it. I opened another question for the Doctrine2 ORM part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610294/cumulative-count-with-doctrine2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can achieve a better performance by sorting the two arrays before doing the comparison.
With two arrays ordered you can avoid doing a **n*m** loop, and stay on **n+m** complexity (plus **n*log n** and **m*log m** for sorting, which anyway is less than n*m)

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the push I needed and I pasted the solution in my question.